# Trouble passing Guid to a Javascript function via onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Ajax call and inside the ajax call's success function there a onclick.I need to pass a Guid value to a another function ,it shows me -1 (here i put alert)

Ajax call

```
 $.each(msg._allProd, function(index, item) {
    debugger;
    //item.PrdId is Guid like 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
    contect = contect + '<div class="item"><a class="item link" onclick="PrdOnClick(item.PrdId)"></div>';
 });
```

And then pass that value to another function

```
function PrdOnClick(id) {
    alert(id); // this alert shows me -1
}
```

Comment: item.PrdId is from some object in C# right?

Comment: Well what I wanted to ask was if `item.PrdId` is some JS object or not. If yes, then you need to look at the answers below. In case it is a C# object, then you need to use proper C# server controls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `item.PrdId` is a variable, you need to use concatenate it properly.

```
contect = contect + '<div class="item"><a class="item link" onclick="PrdOnClick(\'' + item.PrdId + '\')"></div>';
```

Answer (score 3):

if your item.PrdId value is correct, this should solve your problem

```
contect = contect + '<div class="item"><a class="item link" onclick="PrdOnClick(' + item.PrdId + ')"></div>';
```

you just forgot to put quotes correct

Answer (score 2):

You have to put PrdID into the onclick call like this:

```
`onclick="PrdOnClick(' + item.PrdId + ')"></div>'
```